# Are cursors necessary for queries in a procedure?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I'm rather new to Oracle and I was asked to write a procedure to query some data from a table. I built it with 2 arguments, a cursor and a number. Essentially I have:

```
PROCEDURE PROC_NAME (
    cursor_name     IN OUT NOCOPY MY_DEFINED_CURSOR_TYPE,
    a_number       IN NUMBER);
AS
BEGIN

OPEN CURSOR_NAME FOR
    SELECT
        column
    FROM
        table
    WHERE
        table.dat_value > (SYSDATE - a_number);
END PROC_NAME;
```

It works like a charm, and I'm able to fetch the column from the cursor. My problem is that the requester doesn't want to pass in a cursor, they just want to pass in the number. I've never created a procedure that doesn't use a cursor to return the values of a query and the examples I have seen only ever do it that way. Is this possible?

Comment: It sounds like you're just being asked to change the `cursor_name` parameter from `IN OUT` to `OUT`.  As a stylistic thing, I'd put `OUT` parameters after `IN` parameters but that's just a personal preference.

Comment: There are a variety of ways you could return data instead of a cursor.  Can the requester specify what they want back?  A nested table, an associative array, a single scalar value, ...?

Comment: Is the requester used to SQL Server? In SQL Server the return of a cursor is implicit and doesn't need to go through parameter.

Comment: I used a loop and a putline to output the values and that seemed to be good enough for the requester for the weekend. It seems like they went the values returned like variables, but the query can return more than 1 row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a collection:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PROC_NAME (
  a_number  IN  NUMBER,
  numbers   OUT SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST
)
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT number_value
  BULK COLLECT INTO numbers
  FROM   table_name
  WHERE  date_value > (SYSDATE - a_number);
END PROC_NAME;
```

Also, if you don't want to pass in a cursor then you can just pass one out:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROC_NAME (
  a_number  IN  NUMBER,
  numbers   OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
AS
BEGIN
  OPEN numbers FOR
  SELECT number_value
  FROM   table_name
  WHERE  date_value > (SYSDATE - a_number);
END PROC_NAME;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [a function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/subprograms.htm#LNPLS99898) instead ? But it's just a "stylistic" difference compared to procedure out parameter. Anyway the returned value have to be implicitly passed (unlike in SQL Server as noted by @ShannonSeverance).

```
function f(
  p_days in number
) return my_defined_cursor_type is
  v_cur my_defined_cursor_type;
begin
  open v_cur for
    select
        column
    from
        table
    where
        table.dat_value > (sysdate - p_days);

  return v_cur;
end;
/
```

**Usage**

```
declare
  v_cur my_defined_cursor_type := f(42);
begin
  -- use v_cur as you like
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to apply some PL/SQL logic, but remain  using select for querying the data (i.e not *pass in a cursor* - use  [pipelined functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14289/dcitblfns.htm#sthref660).

You need to define the TYPEs of the result row and table; FETCH the cursor and PIPE the results in the function.

```
 CREATE or replace type MY_DEFINED_ROW_TYPE as object
 (
 txt             VARCHAR2(30)
 );
 /

 create or replace type MY_DEFINED_TABLE_TYPE as table of MY_DEFINED_ROW_TYPE
 /


 create or replace function FUN_NAME( a_number  IN NUMBER) return 
 MY_DEFINED_TABLE_TYPE
 PIPELINED
 as
     cur  MY_DEFINED_CURSOR_TYPE;
     v_txt   varchar2(30);
 begin
   OPEN cur
       FOR
       SELECT
        column
       FROM table
       WHERE table.dat_value > (SYSDATE - a_number);
    LOOP
     FETCH cur INTO v_txt;
     EXIT WHEN cur%NOTFOUND; 
     pipe row(v_txt);
    END LOOP;      
    return;
 end;
 /
```

The usage:

```
select * from table (FUN_NAME(2));
```